# OpenLayers map fill full screen?

Tags: javascript, openlayers, css

I have an OpenLayers map with the following css:

```
.map {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

However the map does not fill the whole screen, and it stays like this (take a look at the bottom):

[image: Map image]

Guess it is due to a ratio issue but don't know how to solve it.

> Any idea of how to force the map to fill the whole screen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To fit the map to the full screen in Openlayers, you should adjust your css code like this:

```
#map {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: With this CSS how can you overlay something?

Comment: Can you explain, what exactly you try to achieve?

Comment: I needed in info box to overlay over the map. But I fixed that using z-index